# Can we say "the tree broke down while it was raining cats and dogs" in this situation?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

We have the phrase "**chop or cut down the tree**" which means "​**to make the tree fall down by **cutting it at the base****"

Now it was raining very hard and **the wind cut the tree down** as shown in the above picture.

Can we say "*the tree  broke down while it was raining cats and dogs*"?

I found this in the dictionary

> **[break (something) down or break down (something)](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/break)** : to use force to push (something) to the ground
>
> break a door down
>
> break down a barrier

But I am not sure if "**break down the barrier**" means the barrier got broken at its base/ foot.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, "blew the tree down" or "blew at tree down"? is that a typo?

Comment: We might say the wind **blew a tree down**, but not that it broke it down.

Comment: We wouldn't normally use a humorous expression like 'raining cats and dogs' of weather that was severe enough to be destructive. _The tree was brought down in the storm_ or _blown down by the gale_.

Comment: It can 'rain cats and dogs' (and often does) when no wind is blowing, at least where I live. It is a jocular and informal expression, as is 'raining stair-rods' (do people say that any more?).

Comment: _Then said Ibotíty, “The wind it is which is strong; for the wind broke the tree, and the tree broke the leg of Ibotíty.”_

Answer (score 2):

"Cut" implies both human intent and the use of tools; any literal version of 'cutting down a tree would involve a person using an axe or saw.

"Broke down" is an idiom referring to a machine that fails; if your car stopped working and you were stuck on the side of the road, we'd say your car broke down.

In this instance, we might say that the tree was *knocked down* by the wind. If it were in the news, a newspaper might write that the tree was *uprooted* (though that would mean pulled out of the ground, not snapped as depicted here) or *felled*.

Comment: "he was knocked down" means his whole body fell to the ground but his legs or feet wouldn't get cut off from his body. In my situation, only 80% of the tree fell down and 20% of the tree including its root was still not fallen.

Comment: "Uproot" is also not right because the root of the tree was still in the ground. The root was not pulled out of the ground

Comment: @Tom a tree like this could be described as "knocked down" since most of it is on the ground. It also might be "blown down"